# Newsletter subscription problem during registration in magento2

Tags: magento2, customer, newsletter, registration

I am getting both subscribe and unsubscribe email once i register the customer with selecting subscribe for newsletter with ticking the checkbox.

I am getting both emails one is subscription and unsubscription email.

Why it is like that, is it magento2 bug, Please anyone help me out with this issue.

Comment: Are you using any 3rd part party integrations for the emails  ?

Comment: are there any other modules related to newsletter ?

Comment: yes using smtp for emails, but not for newsletters

Comment: @jafarpinjar, Did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora, yes i removed subscribeCustomerById this line and added my custom code for it, I do not know what was the problem there,